# No WiFi after flashing

Tags: cyanogenmod, wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-3, rom-flashing

A bit of history:

I got this **Samsung Galaxy S III** from T-Mobile **SGH-T999**
Decided to to play with Cyanogenmod.

- Rooted my S3 - success
- Installed Cyanogenmod following instructions - success
- Got notification that Cyanogenmod update available ( around
  2/20/2014) - downloaded and installed the update which **SOFT BRICKED
  my SGIII**

Decided to go back to stock due to these update issues with Cyanogenmod

**RECOVERY PROCESS:**

Used ODIN v.3.04 to flash a stock ROM for my phone that I got from:

http://samsung-updates.com/device/?id=SGH-T999

file name: **T999UVUEMJC_T999TMBEMJC_T999UVUEMJC_HOME.tar.md5**

Successfully flashed it with ODIN

All went well except I **cannot turn on WiFi**.

When I click the WiFi button it turns dark green (apparently trying to turn on WiFi) and then turn back grey

Any help and suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How about you try flashing the stock ROM AGAIN?

Comment: I hooe you've done a full wipe before flashing. Moving from one ROM to another w/o full wipe causes issues.

Comment: Full wipe, reflash the ROM. Also have you flashed the correct Baseband for your device also? If this is a newer version of Android (4.3 - 4.4 particularly) chances are you need a newer modem (baseband). They are here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1880987&page=1 and you can Odin flash them. I often say this, but CyanogenMod is quite buggy in the Nightlies and non stable candidates, expect issues like this to be honest. I'd try the baseband, or start at Stock all over again and reflash, try another ROM also to test.

Comment: @RossC thank you for your advice. I did not do any wipe. Two questions: 1. Can I do full wipe from CWM or there is a special procedure ? 2. I downloaded the modem zip file for my model. Since it is not a tar.md5 I should install it from my SD card using CWM ?

Comment: 1 yes. 2 it depends on the model, as a rule use odin for your baseband! Flash on odin the tar file in phone

Comment: @RossC there is no tar file the baseband file. The baseband is a zip file from the link you provided. When I open it, it shows some folder structure. Should flash it from my SD using CWM ?

Comment: Hmmm mine are zip with a tar inside. What's recommended on that thread? I'd check for you but I'm on my phone and out and about, sorry.

Comment: @geffchang thanks guys. A thorough cleaning of both caches and re-flashing fixed the problem. No everything works great. I appreciate the advice.

Comment: @AstroSharp AWESOME! Just post the steps you did as an answer (e.g. which caches you cleaned, etc), and mark this as accepted 2 days later. :)